# Jenkins does not redirect to HTTPS

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jenkins, hudson

## The problem

I am using Jenkins over `HTTPS/SSL` (the details of setup below). I can navigate to `https://jenkins.mydomain.com:8088` without any problems. All links are correct with `https://` in front of them. I can properly navigate through almost all Jenkins pages.

**Except** when Jenkins tries to redirect (e.g after login, after clicking <kbd>Build</kbd>, etc). Whenever Jenkins tries to redirect to any page, it sends me to `http://` page (not `httpS://`)

## What I've tried

- I have tried setting setting  `Jenkins URL` in global configuration. It works fine for everything, except that it always redirects to `http://`, despite the URL saying `httpS://`
  [image]
- I have tried following [instructions here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) regarding modifying `jenkins.xml` with port configuration, however as my setup is not using Jenkins Windows service install, I simply don't have `jenkins.xml` Is there a different place I can specify the parameters to Jenkins?
- I have tried understanding whatever *"mod_proxy with HTTPS"* means, but I don't have any virtual hosts configuration. And besides, my Tomcat installation is not the one that handles SSL. The issue seems to be only in Jenkins's redirect mechanism, which is ignoring `Jenkins URL` protocol part from Global Configuration.

### The Jenkins setup

- Apache Tomcat running as Windows service

  1. `Jenkins.war` renamed to `ROOT.war` is placed in Tomcat's `webapps` folder
  2. Executing through `bin\tomcat6.exe //RS//Instance_Name`
  3. Configured through Tomcat's Windows "Monitor Service" tool
     [image]
- There are multiple instances configured this way on this machine, differentiated by different Tomcat folders and different Tomcat ports under respective `conf\server.xml`
- I've inherited this setup. Don't know why they didn't use the native install package with Windows service. There are multiple instances of Jenkins (through multiple instances of Tomcat service) on this computer. Trying to change the installation type for all those instances will incur unacceptable amount of downtime.
- Jenkins' port `8088`, cannot use `443` for SSL as there are multiple instances running and they can't all have `443` as the only way Instances are differentiated is by port.

### The SSL setup

- We have a global SSL cert (`*.mydomain.com`) that is hosted on a load balancer hardware.  (I don't have access to actual file)
- There is no SSL on actual Windows server hosting Jenkins.
- The DNS for `jenkins.mydomain.com` resolves to a virtual IP on the load-balancer, which then forwards to traffic to actual Windows server hosting Jenkins.
- There is **nothing wrong** with this setup, it works fine for all other sites. *This SSL setup also works fine for our Jenkins instance*.

Comment: Very long time ago, but can you remember if you solved this? For me all the internal links redirect properly, but the login and the logout always redirect to http instead of https

Comment: @user2782001 I think I gave up on that

Answer (score 1):

I suggest peeking around the server.xml and finding the Connector and adding secure="true" if you are doing an HTTP proxy scheme. Redirect ports may also be involved.

```
<Connector secure="true" port="8088" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
            />
```

For reference,
We run Jenkins behind 2 Apache proxies, one external and one internal:

The relevant parts of our external vhost (jenkins.host.com):

```
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic (encrypted password)"
    ProxyPass / ajp://dev.internal:9101/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://dev.internal:9101/
```

The relevant parts of tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Connector port="9001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
            />

<Connector port="9101" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

<Host name="dev.internal" appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
       <Alias>jenkins.host.com</Alias>

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="dev.internal_access_log." suffix=".txt" rotatable="false"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

Comment: Enabling secure connector did not help. Like I tried to explain, the issue is not in configuring the webserver (Tomcat), as the server hosting Jenkins does not even have the SSL cert and by itself cannot work over SSL with no cert. It's something on Jenkins' configuration...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart the Jenkins server for the global configuration change to take effect. [*Jenkins CI Cookbook*](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9781849517409/1dot-maintaining-jenkins/id286751198) says (highlighting mine):

> Jenkins uses Xstream (http://x-stream.github.io/) to persist its configuration into a readable XML format. The XML files in the workspace are configuration files for plugins, tasks, and an assortment of other persisted information. config.xml is the main configuration file. Security settings and global configuration are set here and reflect changes made through the GUI. Plugins use the same structure, and the XML values correspond to member values in underlying plugin classes. The GUI itself is created from XML through the Jelly framework (http://commons.apache.org/jelly/).
>
> **By restarting the server, you should be certain that any configuration changes are picked up during the initialization phase.**

In addition, to make sure that no one ever accesses the Jenkins server over HTTP (e.g., stale links, typing URL manually in the browser, etc.), you can have the loadbalancer rewrite the `http://` URLs into `https://` URLs.

---

**Edit:** an earlier version of this answer incorrectly suggested the following:

> Tomcat rewrite the `http://` URLs to `https://` URLs by using [urlrewritefilter](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329355/3618671)

which cannot be done because the SSL certificate resides on the loadbalancer which terminates the SSL connection, which means it speaks HTTP to Tomcat, so Tomcat will never see an `https://` URL, so this suggestion would have caused an infinite redirect loop. (Keeping this around because otherwise the comments below won't make sense).

Comment: I was hopeful, but restart did not help. Plus like I mentioned, it does store and retain the domain portion... just not the https part

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but try the Tomcat URL rewriter. It may not the ideal solution (feels more like duct tape), but it would prevent any access over HTTP to Jenkins, which is something you would want even if the HTTPS solution worked.

Comment: Maybe I am being stupid here, but how can I setup any kind of HTTPS on the server if I don't have access to a certificate file?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm assuming that the Tomcat URL rewriter will rewrite `http://` URLs into `https://` URLs and send a 302 redirect back to the client, as is mentioned on their [home page](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/), thus forcing the client's browser to (re-)load the same `host:port/path` but with an HTTPS connection. This (new) request will then hit the loadbalancer which _does_ have your SSL certificate, so it should work as if the user typed `https://host:port/path` manually. Essentially, this makes Tomcat prevent any access to your Jenkins servers via HTTP.

Comment: I think I see your point and my mistake: Tomcat and Jenkins will never see the `https://` URL because the SSL connection is terminated by the loadbalancer (which is the only one that has the certificate) and the connection from loadbalancer to Tomcat is always HTTP, so my suggestion is not feasible. You'll have to do the URL rewriting at the loadbalancer instead, if that's feasible.

Comment: @Slav, did you have any luck in getting to work? BTW, I'd like to offer that we clean up this discussion and the answer by removing unnecessary comments. I've updated the answer to say that the URL rewriting needs to happen on the loadbalancer, not Tomcat. We can now delete our respective comments except for your first comment on this answer, and I can drop the "edit" paragraph. Thoughts?